# Acceder a una propiedad de un objeto desde un array de string

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo un `object` así:

```
{
  var: {
    foo: '',
    foo2: '',
  }
}
```

y me llega en una función un parámetro `(['var', 'foo2'], newData)`. ¿Que tendría que hacer para devolver el objeto original con `var.foo2 = new Data`?

La cantidad de parámetro del array así como el objeto general pueden cambiar :(

he probado:

```
let fields = ['var', 'foo2'];
let obj = objOri;
for (let f of fields) {
  if (obj.hasProperty(f)) {
    obj = obj[f];
  }
}
obj = newData;
console.log(objOri);// Sigue saliendo mal :(
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

En esta línea asignas a la variable obj lo que hay en objOri, para luego recorrer todos los campos y, se supone, ir bajando de nivel dentro de ese objeto:

```
let obj = objOri;
for (let f of fields) {
  if (obj.hasProperty(f)) {
    obj = obj[f];
  }
}
```

Esto funciona para leer el valor de la propiedad actual pero no puedes sustituirla conforme lo haces al final. Lo que podrías probar es a recorrer todos los campos y quedarte con el último para poder hacer algo así:

```
let obj = objOri;
let objFormer = null;
let lastField = null;
for (let f of fields) {
  if (obj.hasProperty(f)) {
    objFormer = obj;
    lastField = f;
    obj = obj[f];
  }
}
objFormer[lastField] = newData;
```

Este es un código muy rudimentario. Creo que es más que mejorable pero es lo primero que se me ha ocurrido

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info, me has dado una idea muy buena. creo una respueta con la solución aplicada.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas tiene naturaleza recursiva. Tu funcion Agregar puede quedar asi (pasando el objeto original como referencia). Puedes usar cuantos niveles quieras en el arbol.

```js
var objOrig = { 
  'var': {
    foo: '',
    foo2: ''
  }
}

function Agregar(obj, arr, fn) {
   if(arr.length) {
      var prop = arr.shift();
      if(arr.length) Agregar(obj[prop], arr, fn); else obj[prop] = fn;
   } 
}

Agregar(objOrig, ['var','foo2'], function() { console.log("hey"); });

console.log(objOrig);

// { var { foo: "", foo2: f() } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado asi :D

```js
let obj = {a: {a: {a: 'aaa'}, b: 'ab'}, b: 'b', c: {a: 'ca', b: 'cb'}};
let fields = ['a', 'b'];
function replaceValue(obj, fields, newValue) {
  let objClone = {};
  let field = fields.shift();
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (key === field) {
      if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && fields.length > 0) {
        objClone[key] = replaceValue(obj[key], fields, newValue);
      } else {
        objClone[key] = newValue;
      }
    } else {
      objClone[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return objClone;
}
console.log(obj);
obj = replaceValue(obj, fields, 'mou');
console.log('resultado', obj);
```

Comment: Te he creado un ejecutable para que cualquiera pueda verlo en funcionamiento :)

Answer (score 0):

Trabajo con vue js y es común esto porque a la par trabajo con laravel. Lo que yo hago es un simple.

Json.parse();

Y cada propiedad de la colección se vuelve accesible como si fuera un objeto.